# NSDateFormatter printing current date in format "M/yyyy hh:mm" in any locale

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Hi I want to print current date in any locale as `M/yyyy hh:mm`.

I was using this method with `currentLocale` as the option in locale.

```
+ (NSString *)dateFormatFromTemplate:(NSString *)template options:(NSUInteger)opts locale:(NSLocale *)locale
```

But it puts locale specific arrangements.

For example in US locale there is a comma in between date and time.

what to do ???? I want no comma just space in every locale...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to format a date in a specific format, then why are you using `dateFormatFromTemplate:`? The purpose of that method is to give you a locale specific format from a general format.

Just use normal `NSDateFormatter` functionality:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"M/yyyy hh:mm"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```